# How do i define short decades for 2000 and 2010?

Tags: grammar, american-english

80's is the eighties  1980 - 1989

90's is the nineties  1990 - 1999

Is it 00's and 01's?

How do i define a decade name for the 2000 and 2010?

Comment: The "aughts" is one way of referring to the first decade of a century, in American English, such as 2000s (decade). From 2000 to 2009. See:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aughts

Comment: What does it mean to call a decade 'short'?

Answer (score 2):

In the English-speaking world, a name for the 2000-2009 decade was never universally accepted in the same manner as for decades such as the '80s, the '90s, etc. You could use the '00s, and the '10s for 2010-2019.

Comment: Was it the same problem for the 1900s and 1910s? Or the century before for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

In Britain, for the 2000-2009 decade, the ***noughties*** (sometimes spelled *naughties*) is quite popular and has an entry in the OED:

The decade from 2000 to 2009.

> 1989   W. Safire in N.Y. Times Mag. 7 May 18/4   That postcard touches
>   on several possibilities suggested by scores of..third-millennium
>   freaks... The Naughties was suggested by 40 readers.
>
> 1990   R. J. A. Smith in Independent (Nexis) 19 Jan. 20   After the
>   Eighties and the Nineties, what should we be calling the next decade?
>   The Noughties?
>
> 1991   New Scientist 14 Sept. 62/3   With regard to Richard Caie's
>   question about suitable names for the next two decades..: considering
>   the moral decline of society as a whole, the next decade must surely
>   be the noughties.
>
> 1996   New Scientist 11 May 80/3   Rachel Oliver thought of a rather
>   more serious difficulty which we will encounter in the year 2000. What
>   will we call the new decade..? To get the ball rolling, Oliver
>   suggests the ‘noughties’.
>
> 2000   Evening Post (Wellington, N.Z.) (Electronic ed.) 1 July   Ditch
>   the mesh handbag, flick the World arm-bands, and dump the diamante
>   butterfly hairclips: the ultimate celebrity-endorsed accessory for the
>   discerning noughties woman is the bloke who is..Just Gay Enough.
>
> 2001   Sunday Times 25 Mar. (Style section) x. 6   The Noughties
>   celebrity face has a line-free forehead and bee-stung lips.

For the current decade, I think the ***twenty-tens*** is about the best anyone has come up with. But it has no entry in the OED.